# TypeError: $http.post(...) . success is not a function

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

i new to Angularjs and i'm working with a tutorial i saw online, i keep getting the TypeError in this section,

> angular.js:14800 TypeError: $http.post(...).success is not a function
>       at Object.authFactory.login (authService.js:15)
>       at Object.vm.doLogin (mainCtrl.js:25)

Kindly find my code below:

index.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <!-- <> -->
    <title>user story </title>

    <script type ="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js'></script>


    <!-- services -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/services/authService.js"></script>

    <!-- controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
  </head>
```

routes

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['appRoutes', 'mainCtrl', 'authService']);
```

authService

```
angular.module('authService',[])

.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken){

  var authFactory  = {};

  authFactory.login = function(username, password){

    return $http.post('/api/login',{
      username: username,
      password: password
    })
    .success(function(data){
      AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
      return data;
    })

});
```

my controller

```
 angular.module('mainCtrl', [])


.controller('MainController', function($rootScope, $location, Auth){

  var vm = this;

vm.doLogin = function(){

    vm.processing = true;
    vm.error = '';
    Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
    .success(function(data){
        vm.processing = false;

        Auth.getUser()
        .then(function(data){
          vm.user = data.data;
        });
      if(data.success)
        $location.path('/');
      else
        vm.error = data.message;
      });
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to find a tutorial for the version fo Angular you are using.

Comment: use `.then((res) => {AuthToken.setToken(res.data.token); return res.data;})`

Comment: Thanks! it worked